# Natural Language Process using SharpNLP with a sample

Tags: visual-studio, nlp, sharpnlp

I am really new to C# and want to do a NLP project using SharpNLP. I know Currently it provides the following NLP tools:
sentence splitter
tokenizer
part-of-speech tagger
chunker 
parser
name finder
coreference tool
interface to the WordNet lexical database

I tried several examples (i have those .nbin models) but failed to integrate the SharNLP tools to VS 2015. Can anyone give some guidance or samples to use this sharpNLP tool with VS. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have successfully created a sample project for newbies. You can get the project from the following link. PS:Please change the nbin file path as your's computer file path. Hope this will help.

Click [HERE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3XcMZLArSF1UURzODRiVmE0RUE/view?usp=sharing) for Sample Project or as below.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3XcMZLArSF1UURzODRiVmE0RUE/view?usp=sharing